# Print an object's attribute from dictionary -python

Tags: python

First can we add an object into python dictionary? 
Second, how can we print object's attribute.
There are my codes

in my c.py

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.wage = 0.0
    def setwage(self,wage):
        self.wage=wage
    def getwage(self):
        return self.wage
```

in my a.py

```
import c
dustin = c.C()

dustin.setwage(6.9)
dic={}

# can I add dustin as an object into dic?
dic['1st employee']=dustin   

for a in dic.items():
    # I want to print dustin object's attribute wage
    print("wage:", a.getwage())
```

Comment: How can you possibly have such a high reputation and can't solve something as simple as this?

Comment: @JamesMills The one *edited* question is not the one *asked*

Comment: Oh I see?! I'm so confused :)

Comment: Ahhh! I see! I haven't seen a question being reviewed before :)

Comment: @JamesMills: Don't confuse the editor with the person asking the question. :-P

Comment: Yeah I see it now! Just surprised from a visual UI perspective :)

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there; you want to loop over the dictionary *values*:

```
for a in dic.values():
    print("wage:", a.getwage())
```

Alternatively, when looping of the items of a dictionary, make use of the fact that each item is a tuple with `(key, value)`:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
    print(key, "wage:", value.getwage())
```

So, yes, you can store instances in dictionaries (most of python makes use of this fact).

Note that getters and setters are not really needed in Python; you can simplify your code :

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.wage = 0.0
```

and then use:

```
dustin = c.C()

dustin.wage = 6.9
dic = {}

dic['1st employee'] = dustin

for key, value in dic.items():
    print(key, "wage:", value.wage)
```

e.g. access the `wage` attribute directly.

Comment: I updated the previous question. Add one more file. Now I want to print the list from the dictionary I created before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551917/print-list-in-a-dictionary-python